# vertically centering a div in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to vertically center a div in a div.My outer div is fullscreen it covers the whole screen.And my inner div is in `position:relative` .

### My codes structure is :

```
<div class="fullscreen">
   <div class="fullscreen-centered">
       <p>...........</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

### My css codes are

```
.fullscreen-centered{
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform:translateY(-50%); 
 }
```

It works fine . But Im also using skrollr.js to add some parallax effect to inner div . That's why when i use `data-top=transform:0px` in order to use a effect , this is replaced by above `transform` so it loses its centered position.

Another Hack can be `display:table-cell` but it does not working.
Is there another way rather than using `transform`?

Comment: Do you know the height of your inner div?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table(-cell)` and `vertical-align` without `position: relative;` and `transform`s.

```
<style>
    .fullscreen {background: #eee; width: 600px; height: 300px; display: table;} 
    .fullscreen-centered{display: table-cell; background: #ccc; vertical-align: middle;}
</style>

<div class="fullscreen">
    <div class="fullscreen-centered">
        <p>...........</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6aw776c/

Comment: See the fiddle I put into my answer, it works. If it doesn't work for you, you probably have an error elsewhere :-) Put the link to your site, or try to debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parallax effect is created using 3D transforms, translating an element along the Z axis has a side effect - its effective size changes as we move it closer to or farther away from the viewport. To counter this we need to apply a `scale()` transform to the element so that it appears to be rendered at its original size:

```
transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
```

It Might help you..!!